# Path used by phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to import a "load.sql" file. In my "load.sql" file, I'm trying to load data specified in a "movie.del" file. However, in my load.sql file, I used a local math path, i.e., ~/Desktop/tmp/movie.del

Phpmyadmin yelled at me and said that it doesn't know where it is...
Could anyone help me figure out the correct path that I'm suppose to provide so that the webserver phpmyadmin can locate that file and so that I can load the values into my tables?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: **How** did you try to import the file? Why not use MySQL directly?

Answer (score 0):

You're on mac I assume?  No matter really.

Type this in terminal...

cd ~/

Then

pwd

That shows your the current directory you are in (aka your user folder in this case which is what ~/ stands for)

so

~/Desktop/tmp/movie.del

=

/Users/username/Desktop/tmp/movie.del